# Random images in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

## This is the function that picks a random image from the array

```
function GetRandomImage(){
           
           let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * image_array.length);
        
           let selectedImg = image_array[randomIndex];
        
           img1.src = `./img/${selectedImg}`;
           img2.src = `./img/${selectedImg}`;
           img3.src = `./img/${selectedImg}`;
        }
```

Now, this generates 3 times the same image, I suppose I have to use a loop to get all 3 images to be a different random (with still the possibility of being the same image).

img1,2,3 are the following, 3 standard images that change after a click of a button[image]
Fairly new so any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enumerate the `<img>` elements into an iterable data structure, then loop that iterable to calculate a random image for each and apply it to the current element's `src` attribute:

```
function GetRandomImage() {
  const imageElements = [img1, img2, img3];
  // could also interrogate the DOM instead:
  // const imageElements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  
  // loop each image element
  for (element of imageElements) {
    // select a new random index
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * image_array.length);
    
    // set the src of the current image element
    let selectedImg = image_array[randomIndex];
    element.src = `./img/${selectedImg}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, so you just group them to be able to use them in a loop?

Comment: I suppose you could call it "grouping" them - at a basic level, you need to stuff them in something that is "[iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#iterators)", meaning it can be looped over easily. In the code above I've defined an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), one of the more basic iterable data structures in JavaScript. (1/2)

Comment: The alternative I provided as a comment in my example (the call to [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which functions similarly to `Array` (with some specialty functionality relating to the nodes in the list). If any of this is foreign to you, I would recommend reading the docs I've linked to get your fundamentals up to speed. (2/2)